# Why is parskip=half messing up the spacing in mdframed?

Tags: spacing, koma-script, mdframed, parskip

without parskip:

[image: no parskip]

parskip=half:

[image: parskip half]

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{gray!25}

\newmdtheoremenv[
  innerlinewidth=0pt,middlelinewidth=0pt,
  outerlinecolor=shadecolor,outerlinewidth=3pt,
  skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip,
  ]{example}{Example}   

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \blindtext
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you don't set the `innertopmargin`, you have the default value, that the manual specifies as `.4\baselineskip`. A workaround is

```
\newmdtheoremenv[
  innerlinewidth=0pt,middlelinewidth=0pt,
  outerlinecolor=shadecolor,outerlinewidth=3pt,
  skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip,
  %%% kill the initial \parskip
  innertopmargin=\dimexpr.4\baselineskip-\parskip\relax,
  %%%
  ]{example}{Example}
```

but this should probably be corrected in `mdframed`, maybe with a new key `suppressfirstparskip`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I'll open an issue at github.

Comment: @neo: You don't need. I am here ;-)

Comment: @neo: Fixed issue: https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed and the new option is `suppressfirstparskip`;-)