# Why is thmtools and mdframed not working with parskip

Tags: theorems, mdframed, parskip, thmtools

I have the following MWE:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


% DEFINITIONS ===================================================
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside,
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    notebraces={[}{]},
    bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
    headpunct={},
    postheadspace=\newline,
    postheadhook={\textcolor{red}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},
    spacebelow=0,
    spaceabove=0,
    mdframed={
        linecolor=red, 
        outerlinewidth=3pt,
            innertopmargin=0pt,
            roundcorner=5pt, 
            innerbottommargin=0pt, 
            skipabove=-\parskip, 
            skipbelow=0 } 
]{myFramedDefinitionStyle}%

\declaretheorem[
    style=myFramedDefinitionStyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{example1}

% Basic Command
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{example} { o o }
     {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#1} {\begin{example1}}{ \begin{example1}[#1] }%                                 
      \IfNoValueTF{#2} {}{\label{#2}}%
     }%
     {%
      \end{example1}%
     }%
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
asdasd
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}
asdasd
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Which results in this output, and I am really asking what I am doing wrong?
Why is parksip messing up the boxes? Also the workaround from [LINK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100570/why-is-parskip-half-messing-up-the-spacing-in-mdframed) does not help?
Does anybody know why this mdframed with thmtools behaves so badly?

Thanks a lot! :-)!!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you spelled `parskip` as `parsep`.  That is, if you change the four instances of `\parsep` into four `\parskip`s, then it seems to work as you intended (or at least better).

**Edited to add:**  Now you have (inside the `mdframed`) a negative value of `skipabove`, so it seems reasonable that it overlaps with the previous paragraph.  Try `skipabove=2\parskip` or something similar.

Comment: Correct, i did not want this, but as it seems i still get issues with the vertical spaces. It seems it depends on the version of mdframed somehow...?
I corrected the parskip parsep issue above

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: correctly, there is still some bad stuff going on?

Comment: @Gabriel, please see my new edit.